# Pattern matching in Typescript over subclasses

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching

Assume the following type hierarchy:

```js
interface Animal {
   //...
}

class Dog implements Animal {
   //...
}

class Cat implements Animal {
  //...
}
```

Now, I have a variable `let l:Array<Animal> = [new Dog(...),new Cat(...)]` somwhere in my code, and I want to map over that array and perform different operations depending on whether i look at a `Dog` instance or a `Cat` instance, and in ideal case using a procedure such as pattern matching. I am thinking of pattern matching in other functional languages such as Scala or Haskell:

```scala
l.map((a:Animal) => match a {case Cat => ..., case Dog => ... })
```

Which ways are there to code/emulate a pattern match like this over subtypes in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no pattern matching syntax in JavaScript, so there is no such syntax in TypeScript either (as that would be runtime syntax and TypeScript no longer adds that, it relies on additions to JavaScript)

You can use type guards. If you are dealing with classes, the best type guard to use is `instanceof`.

```
let l = [new Cat(), new Dog()];
l.map((a:Animal) => 
    a instanceof Dog ? a.isGoodBoy() :
    a instanceof Cat ? a.sayName(): 
    a.speak())
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwFgAoZM5AZwAcI4BrACgEoAuZANwHtgATE85AHpBAOjEkAviRIIccChWQARTgHNkWKjgiYI4Reiy4C-cgGJgFAOKdOPAEKcAnsgC8yMFACuEU2Wq0jKwc3DwmpALkCJwgFJzaIjhqDABEAEZwUHQpTADcfshSEWSWNnaOTszhkVExcQlJqgxgABaWIhbWtg7OeQVFApLSxLLyigDCcGAamFo6emAGGNh4RMXIZiBwum7IKSkFAfTMbFy81TXI0bHxEInJKZjAcF45+esD5BRwTgBy2xAqmtLlc6rd7k1Wu1NgC+h8hsQSNppnh3ABtEAQADuyEmYGYABpkJicSomkwALrvHAibBUBgMOAsQwrJhuAB8yAKcA0sTAcBASE4MGUamQAH5kHARKVuhUqixubyKPzBRBhbiphKpSJvn8AScuetpUcgkwgA)